# How do I display width percentage in jquery when using if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a progress bar that is controlled by an input field. When the user updates the number the progress bar will scale to that percentage. I am trying to have words highlight when the progress bar passes a curtain percentage. How can this be achieved in JQuery.

Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="progress-container">
    <span class="progress-line" style="width:<?php the_field($post-name, $page-id); ?>%"></span>
</div>

<ul>
    <li class="progress-asia">South East Asia</li>
    <li class="progress-australia">Australia</li>
    <li class="progress-new-zealand">New Zealand</li>
    <li class="progress-america">America</li>
    <li class="progress-home">Home</li> 
</ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var perc = $('.progress-line').width();

    if (perc > width('10%')) {
        $('.progress-asia').addClass('progress-active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var perc = $('.progress-line').width(),
        container = $('.progress-container').width();

    // you need to compare the current progress width to the
    // container progress width.
    // the returned value is the % completed
    perc = perc / container * 100;
    if (perc > 10) {
        $('.progress-asia').addClass('progress-active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare with the size of the whole document:

```
if (perc > 0.1 * $(document).width()) {
```